# Ngrok in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ngrok

I need to use the ngrok tunnel for a project I am working on. I have added the extension on VS 2019, the only version available is 0.9.13.When I try to run the ngrok tunnel its asked me do I want to install version 2.3.35. After I select yes I it then tells me that Access to the path is denied. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the ngrok website (ngrok.com), sign up and/or login, and download the latest version for Windows. At time of writing, it's a zip that contains a single file: `ngrok.exe`. Once you download it, extract the exe to the Visual Studio IDE path where the ngrok error is looking for it. For example, mine is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE`. Once it's there, this should make it so within Visual Studio 2019 you can go to `Tools > Start ngrok Tunnel` in the menu up top and it will actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same thing. The only workaround I've found is to run Visual Studio as Administrator: Right click the Visual Studio icon, click "Run as administrator" in the context menu. Not ideal, but works for those times I need ngrok.